# Llamar a una función de la ventana principal en popup

Tags: php, facebook

Tengo en la página principal un script con el siguiente código:

```
function preparar(data){
   // algún código
}
```

En la ventana popup:

```
opener.preparar(datos);
//windows.opener.preparar()... etc
```

Pero lanza el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://mi_dominio.com" 
from facebook-callback.php?...... accessing a cross-origin frame. at 
https://mi_dominio.com/..../facebook-callback.php?......
```

Estoy haciendo un login con facebook (popup), usando el sdk php.

Answer (score 0):

**Política del mismo origen**

*No debe confundirse con CORS!*

> No puede acceder a un `<iframe>` con origen diferente usando
>   JavaScript, sería un gran error de seguridad si pudiera hacerlo. Para
>   los navegadores de políticas de origen idéntico, bloquean los scripts
>   que intentan acceder a un marco con un origen diferente.
>
> El origen se considera diferente si al menos una de las siguientes
>   partes de la dirección no se mantiene:

```
<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/path/to/page.html
```

**Protocolo**, **nombre de host** y puerto deben ser los mismos de su **dominio**, si desea acceder a un frame.

**Ejemplos**

Esto es lo que sucedería al intentar acceder a las siguientes URL desde http://www.example.com/home/index.html

```
URL                                             RESULT 
http://www.example.com/home/other.html       -> Success 
http://www.example.com/dir/inner/another.php -> Success 
http://www.example.com:80                    -> Success (default port for HTTP) 
http://www.example.com:2251                  -> Failure: different port 
http://data.example.com/dir/other.html       -> Failure: different hostname 
https://www.example.com/home/index.html.html -> Failure: different protocol 
ftp://www.example.com:21                     -> Failure: different protocol & port 
https://google.com/search?q=james+bond       -> Failure: different hostname & protocol
```

**Solución**

Aunque la política del mismo origen bloquea las secuencias de comandos para acceder al contenido de sitios con un origen diferente, si tiene ambas páginas, puede solucionar este problema utilizando [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)  y su evento de mensaje relativo para enviar mensajes entre las dos páginas, como esta:

En tu página principal:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('your-frame-id'); 

frame.contentWindow.postMessage(/*alguna variable o objecto*/, '*');
```

En su `<iframe>` (contenido en la página principal):

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 


// IMPORTANTE: ¡comprueba el origen de los datos!
    if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://tusitio.com')) { 
        // Los datos han sido enviados desde su sitio

// Los datos enviados con postMessage se almacenan en event.data        console.log(event.data); 
    } else { 
        return; 
    } 
});
```

> Este método se puede aplicar en ambas direcciones, creando un oyente
>   en la página principal también y recibiendo respuestas del marco. La
>   misma lógica también se puede implementar en ventanas emergentes y,
>   básicamente, en cualquier ventana nueva generada por la página
>   principal (por ejemplo, usando window.open ()), sin ninguna
>   diferencia.
>
> Deshabilitar la política del mismo origen en su navegador Ya hay
>   algunas buenas respuestas sobre este tema (acabo de encontrarlas en
>   Google), entonces, para los navegadores donde esto sea posible,
>   vincularé la respuesta relativa. Sin embargo, recuerde que
>   deshabilitar la política de origen idéntico (o CORS) solo afectará a
>   su navegador. Además, ejecutar un navegador con la configuración de
>   seguridad del mismo origen deshabilitada otorga a cualquier sitio web
>   acceso a recursos de origen cruzado, por lo que es muy inseguro y debe
>   hacerse solo para fines de desarrollo.

- Google Chrome

  - Mozilla Firefox
  - Apple Safari: no es posible, solo CORS.
  - Opera: no es posible.
  - Microsoft Edge: no es posible.
  - Microsoft Internet Explorer: no es posible, solo CORS.

Autor de la respuesta: [marco bonelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889449/marco-bonelli)

pregunta original :[security error blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: vale, muchas gracias. Cuando trabaja sólo con http funcionaba bien, luego de implementar https, fue que genero ese error, y no se como arreglarlo, el popup se llama a facebook-login.php que es en mismo dominio